# Request.post arguments in python

Tags: json, python-3.x

Is there a way to determine the max value of an argument in a `requests.post` command to a website if we don't know the amount of data in the website's dataset?  I'm trying to execute the following code to get specific information on all daycares from this website, but don't know the value of the last argument (length).  Currently, I'm assuming this value is 20, but it is subject to change from time to time.  How do I keep it open ended so I don't have to guess the max value for lenth?  Code as follows:

```
data_requested = requests.post("https://data.nj.gov/views/INLINE/rows.json?"
        "accessType=WEBSITE&method=getByIds&asHashes=true&start=0&length=20",
        json=data)
njcc_data = data_requested.json()
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice that this has nothing to do with `requests.post` - the range of values `length` can take is determined by the creator of that API and is an unknown quantity both to you and to `requests`.

You can try to reason about what possible values it could take, is it the length of a person? If yes, it's probably not going to be more than 250cm.

You can also use trial and error and see how high you can make it before the API endpoint gives back an error, but I guess this is what you were trying to avoid.

If length is the number of items returned (the length of the returned json array) then you could just try setting it to a high number like 1000 and see if you can get away with it.